# Ant SecureInputHandler: prints password in clear text when used with tee

Tags: ant, tee

We use Ant's secure handler to enter passwords:

```
<input message="Please enter TFS password: " addproperty="tfs.password">
  <handler type="secure"/> 
</input>
```

That, of course, does work: input is not printed.

When though (to save the build log) we run the build as

```
ant | tee build.log
```

the input is printed in clear text. Oops.

I wonder where is the issue (ant? tee?) and how to fix that.

P.S. OS:

```
Linux devosb1 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu 
SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

P.P.S. OK, so it is not tee -- a shell script with read/echo instead of tee triggers the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a shell issue. Have you considered using the [ANT record](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) task?

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

    <target name="build">
        <record name="build.log" loglevel="verbose"/>

        <input message="Please enter TFS password: " addproperty="tfs.password">
            <handler type="secure"/> 
        </input>
    </target>

</project>
```